# Why does a search (wherehas) for decimal column in a relationship take so long in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a list where I return products from laravel, This list has search box for each column, And for this i am using something like:

```
    $q = Product::query();
    $q->where('account_id', Auth::user()->account_id);
    if ($request->code) {
        $q->where('code', 'LIKE' , "%{$request->code}%");            
    }

    if ($request->title) {
        $q->where('title', 'LIKE' , "%{$request->title}%");            
    }
    if ($request->price){
        $q->whereHas('price', function($query) use ($request){
            $query->where('price' ,$request->price);
        });
    }
    $products = $q->with('price', 'images')
        ->orderBy('id','desc')->paginate($limit);
```

when I don't use the price section, there is no problem and very fast, But when I use the price then it takes a very long time. The price column is a decimal.

the relationship for product->price is:

```
public function price()
{
    // hasOne(RelatedModel, foreignKeyOnRelatedModel = product_id, localKey = id)
    return $this->hasOne(Price::class);
}
```

Actually, I could use a raw query and join instead but because I am using a chain query and pagination I cant do that.

Is there any suggestion for this to make the process faster?

Comment: That would generate a subquery. Check the generated sql and verify that you have an index on the `price` column (and that it is used).

Comment: yes you are right. All columns of the prices table are already indexed. and this is the query (subquery as you said)  select * from `products` where exists (select * from `product_prices` where `products`.`id` = `product_prices`.`product_id` and `price` LIKE ?)

Comment: I used the query with my local sql (sequel) but takes the same time as exected.

Comment: Are you sure that the generated sql query does a `... AND price LIKE ?`? I presumed it would be a `... AND price = ?` Using LIKE will probably force all your decimal columns to be treated like strings and invalidate any use of existing indexes.

Comment: Hey awesome. That was it. After using it without LIKE it worked.

Comment: @sisve could you please make this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the comments, the generated query had a LIKE-clause.

```
SELECT * FROM products
 WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM product_prices
                 WHERE products.id = product_prices.product_id
                   AND price LIKE ? )
```

This will convert not only the value used in the filter, but all values in the product_prices table, into strings for the purpose of calculating matches. This means that no indexes are used, so the query becomes a full table scan, which is slower than an index lookup.

I presume that the actual code being used has copy/pasted the other clauses for code and title; thus it were also using a LIKE query. However, this isn't shown in the actual question.

The solution is to do an normal equality comparison instead, which allows the use of the existing indexes.

```
SELECT * FROM products
 WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM product_prices
                 WHERE products.id = product_prices.product_id
                   AND price = ? )
```

Answer (score 2):

Create another migration and [add an index](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations#creating-indexes) to the `price` column in the `prices` table:

```
$table->index('price');
```